# why OpenCV cv2.resize gives different answer than MATLAB imresize?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, numpy, image-resizing

I'm transferring a MATLAB code into python and trying to downscale an image using OpenCV function `cv2.resize`, But I get a different results from what MATLAB outputs.

To make sure that my code is not doing anything wrong before the resize, I used a small example on both functions and compared the output.

I first created  the following array in both Python and MATLAB and upsampled it:

#### Python - NumPy and OpenCV

```
    x = cv2.resize(np.array([[1.,2],[3,4]]),(4,4), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    print x

    [[ 1.    1.25  1.75  2.  ]
     [ 1.5   1.75  2.25  2.5 ]
     [ 2.5   2.75  3.25  3.5 ]
     [ 3.    3.25  3.75  4.  ]]
```

#### MATLAB

```
    x = imresize([1,2;3,4],[4,4],'bilinear')

    ans =

    1.0000    1.2500    1.7500    2.0000
    1.5000    1.7500    2.2500    2.5000
    2.5000    2.7500    3.2500    3.5000
    3.0000    3.2500    3.7500    4.0000
```

Then I took the answers and resized them back to the original 2x2 size.

#### Python:

```
    cv2.resize(x,(2,2), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

    ans = 

     [[ 1.375,  2.125],
      [ 2.875,  3.625]]
```

#### MATLAB:

```
    imresize(x,[2,2],'bilinear')

    ans =

      1.5625    2.1875
      2.8125    3.4375
```

They are clearly not the same, and when numbers are larger, the answers are a lot more different.

Any explanation or resources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

MATLAB's [`imresize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html) has [anti-aliasing enabled by default](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/resizing-an-image.html#f12-24819):

```
>> imresize(x,[2,2],'bilinear')
ans =
    1.5625    2.1875
    2.8125    3.4375
>> imresize(x,[2,2],'bilinear','AntiAliasing',false)
ans =
    1.3750    2.1250
    2.8750    3.6250
```

This has tripped me up in the past, while trying to [reproduce the results of `imresize` using just `interp2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20009314/2778484).

Comment: +1 Thank you! That is exactly what i was looking for.
I have been using this function for many years, and never thought about turning off the anti-aliasing. 
Do you know if there is a way to do such down-sampling in python that does have anti-aliasing instead of implementing it?

Comment: @mxy I'm afraid not. Perhaps you can first convolve with a Gaussian or  other low pass filter prior to resize/resample.