# imresize undefined

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I am loading an image in MATLAB and trying to resize it to certain size. This is my code:

```
img = imread(strcat(train_path,'/','aa.jpg' ));
[w h d] = size(img);
fprintf('%s %d %d %d \n', strcat(train_path,'/','aa.jpg' ), w, h ,d );

%image(img)
resize_img = imresize(img, [96,96]);
```

All works well except the `imresize` function. The error is `imresize` undefined.

Comment: If you can't get `imresize`, consider rolling your own with `interp2`.  See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20009314/2778484) for a starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the image processing toolbox for [imresize](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html?searchHighlight=imresize), but not for imread, which is included in Matlab by default.
http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/

Comment: how do I load image processing toolbox in my script ?

Comment: is it installed?  type `ver` to see your installed toolboxes

Comment: I used ver, found no packages installed, I am using on octave, I will try to download and install

Comment: Hi,honi, I have downloaded one from http://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20Forge%20Packages/R2009-06-07/, image-1.0.10.tar.gz, is it ? as I downloaded it, how should i install with octave

Comment: Hi, honi, I tried the command in octave, but with warming, warning: file -forge does not exist
warning: file image does not exist

Comment: in octave, cd to the directory where you have the download and then try `pkg install image-1.0.10.tar.gz`

Comment: alternatively, you can try updating octave to the newest version and then trying the `pkg install -forge image` command again

Comment: I follow this, http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Installing-and-Removing-Packages.html, replace image-1.0.0.tar.gz with image-1.0.10.tar.gz, no work. so should I download the package firstly, put into a installation folder and then use the command ?

Comment: does `pwd` in octave give the same folder where the file is stored?  if not, cd to the correct folder

Comment: HI, honi, I cd to the folder in octave where the package is, tried the pkg install command, it worked in half that a error popped up, saying error: called from `pkg>configure_make' in file /usr/share/octave/3.2.4/m/pkg/pkg.m near line 1253, column 2. perhaps I would reinstall octave in latest version

Comment: what is the entire error? do you have make installed?  what does `which make` do if you type it in at the command line?  what system are you on?

Comment: on ubuntu 12.04, make is installed with version 3.81, octave version is 3.2.4.  the entire error is make: mkoctfile: Command not found
make: *** [__spatial_filtering__.oct] Error 127
'make' returned the following error: make: Entering directory `/tmp/oct-nbDhlk/image-1.0.10/src'
mkoctfile __spatial_filtering__.cc
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/oct-nbDhlk/image-1.0.10/src'
error: called from `pkg>configure_make' in file /usr/share/octave/3.2.4/m/pkg/pkg.m near line 1253, column 2
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.2.4/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 714, column 5

Comment: in my command line, make is installed, but in octave, if type 'make -v', then says 'error: `make' undefined'

Comment: everyone seems to think that you should try installing using apt-get: `sudo apt-get install octave-image` http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Ubuntu-12-04-quot-pkg-install-quot-does-not-work-td4657080.html

Comment: I think that is right , a big hug to u, honi. one more question, if I want to install other packages, just apt-get install octave-package-name, is it ?

Comment: thats what it seems.  i dont use octave that often so im not 100%

Answer (score 2):

In octave you need to load image processing package at the beginning of your code

```
pkg load image
img = imread(strcat(train_path,'/','aa.jpg' ));
...
```

it adds the image package to the path.